# Assign same category to similar messages

Tags: python, regex, categories

I have this simple `Categorizer`:

```
import re


class Categorizer:

    '''
    Classifies messages according to a pre-defined list of regex-es
    If no match is found, an automatic algorithm is used to decide the category
    '''

    def __init__(self, categories, message):
        self._categories = categories
        self._message = message

    def _auto_detec_category(self):
        # TODO: auto-detect category based on message (message distance / bayes classifier / ...)
        return message

    @property
    def category(self):
        '''Returns the first matching category, or an automaticaly generated one if no match found'''
        for category, regex in self._categories.items():
            if regex.search(self._message):
                return category
        return self._auto_detec_category()


CATEGORIES = {
    "aaa": "aaa.*AAA",
    "bbb": "bbb.*BBB",
}


categories = { category: re.compile(regex) for category, regex in CATEGORIES.items() }

MESSAGES = [
    "aaa 12345 AAA",
    "aaa 66666 AAA",
    "bbb 12345 BBB",
    "bbb 66666 BBB",
    "ccc 12345 CCC",
    "ccc 66666 CCC",
]


for message in MESSAGES:
    print("{} -> {}".format(Categorizer(categories, message).category, message))
```

Which gives me this:

```
aaa -> aaa 12345 AAA
aaa -> aaa 66666 AAA
bbb -> bbb 12345 BBB
bbb -> bbb 66666 BBB
ccc 12345 CCC -> ccc 12345 CCC
ccc 66666 CCC -> ccc 66666 CCC
```

My goal is that not pre-configured patterns can still be classified so that similar messages get assigned the same category. But I am not sure how to define "similar", or what implementation to use in order to ensure that the `Categozier` is doing a good job with unknown messages.

Those messages are log entries, with generic information but also some specific data which shouldn't be relevant to select the category.

Basically, I would be satisfied with an output like this:

```
aaa -> aaa 12345 AAA
aaa -> aaa 66666 AAA
bbb -> bbb 12345 BBB
bbb -> bbb 66666 BBB
auto1 -> ccc 12345 CCC
auto1 -> ccc 66666 CCC
```

Where the two last messages are auto-classified as `auto1`.

Comment: Please give some examples of "similar" messages and also of messages that appear somewhat similar yet do not belong in the same category.

Comment: @JanneKarila the messages are already listed in the answer: "aaa" messages are similar to each other, "bbb" messages too, "ccc" messages too, and they are all distinct to each other. What I am looking for is a way to compute the "distance" of messages to each other, and use a threshold to decide when they are the "same" message. There is no definition of what "similar" means, apart from "what is below the threshold provided by the metric".

Comment: Given those examples, the simple solution would be to extract the first word of each message and categorize on that alone.

Comment: @JanneKarila The messages are not similar to each other because they start with the same letter, but because they are "close to each other according to a metric". I want to know what text metrics are available, and how to compute metrics in python.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comment, I don't think regular expressions is the tool you want.

Have you tried using the `fuzzywuzzy` library (see [Docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy)). It allows you to compare the "closeness" of two strings. Its not perfect, but in your case, I would try comparing the "closeness" of each of your log entries to some set of standards. Here I classify by the closest match.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

message = [
    'aaa 12345 AAA',
    'aaa 66666 AAA',
    'bbb 12345 BBB',
    'bbb 66666 BBB',
    'ccc 12345 CCC',
    'ccc 66666 CCC',
]

def classify(input_str):
    # Define standard classifications, and reset them to zero score.
    standards = {
        'AAA': 0,
        'BBB': 0,
        'CCC': 0,
    }

    # Score each classification according to how well is matches.
    for key in standards:
        standards[key] = fuzz.ratio(key, input_str)

    # Return the classification with the highest score.
    return max(standards, key=lambda k: standards[k])


for msg in messages:
    print ('{msg}: {standard}'.format(msg=msg, standard=classify(msg)))
```